# Dataview.dataview vs Dataview.list

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here is my Dataview.List

[image]

Here is my Dataview.Dataview

[image]

I want to display items from my Dataview.dataview the same has in my Dataview.List. I just can't figure what is the property Im looking for to modify...

Explicitly, I want to remove the gap between elements and only have Top and Bot element to have round exteriors edges.

I can't transform my dataview.dataview to a dataview.list has I need it that way to display component view objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY default there is no gap, a property was wrongly set to a padding of 10px on bottom, creating this gap...